# \subsection{AAA \Rey } error in beamer

Tags: beamer, errors

My MWE is

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetheme{Berkeley}


\newcommand\Rey{\mbox{\textit{Re}}}  

\begin{document}



\section{A section}
\subsection{AAA \Rey }
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title1}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle1}
  Some text s
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But it get errors:

```
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 \subsection{AAA \Rey }
```

Want to get help, Thanks. :-D

Comment: Try `\subsection{AAA \protect\Rey }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `\Rey` is for the [*Reynolds number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number), then you should use a different definition:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\newcommand\Rey{\mathit{Re}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\subsection{AAA $\Rey$}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title1}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle1}
  Some text s
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you want to avoid the warning about

```
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
removing `math shift'
```

then say

```
\subsection{AAA \texorpdfstring{$\Rey$}{Re}}
```

I'm not sure if the symbol should be typeset in italics, but it will be easy to change the definition to

```
\newcommand\Rey{\mathrm{Re}}
```

in case you decide to print it upright.

Comment: A better alternative I think.:-D. I will then replace it as a math form including Str and Pr. Thanks.